# Weird order in jQuery collection filled with DOM elements and virtual elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm writing my own jQuery plugin in which I'm referencing some existing nodes and also creating some new jQ nodes that do not exist in the DOM tree (they're not appended). I'm using the [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method to add each element into a new collection.

What happens is, the order of this collection looks weird (I can't find any logical pattern there). The following note in documentation might be the reason why:

> As of jQuery 1.4 the results from .add() will always be returned in document order (rather than a simple concatenation).

Consider the following example.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <a id="existing1"></a><a id="existing2"></a>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function addToColl(selector) {
        coll = coll.add(selector);
        var n = $(selector).get(0).id.match(/\d+/)[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            var a = $('<a>',{id:'virtual'+n+'_'+i});
            coll = coll.add(a);
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        coll = $();

        addToColl('#existing1');
        // uncomment the following to see what's happening
        //addToColl('#existing2');

        $.each(coll,function(idx,elm) {
            console.log(elm.id);
        });

    });

</script>
```

**Outputs:**

> existing1
>   virtual1_0
>   virtual1_1
>   virtual1_2
>   virtual1_3

When you uncomment the commented function call it outputs

> existing1
>   virtual1_3
>   virtual1_2
>   virtual1_1
>   virtual1_0
>   existing2
>   virtual2_0
>   virtual2_1
>   virtual2_2
>   virtual2_3

What should be done to avoid this mess?

**------ [EDIT] ------**
Due to the unexpected behavior of the `add()` function I ended up using a native Javascript array to collect the elements (namely using the `push()` method). Later, when I'm done with collecting the elements I'm converting it into a jQuery collection.

Comment: Did you try to define coll = $([]); instead of coll = $();

Comment: The comment in the documentation only applies if all the elements in the collection are in the DOM. If not, the order is unpredictable due to the way it merges collections.

Comment: @YoniBaciu it didn't change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: @Barmar I think, internally it searches the elements in the DOM tree first and it recreates the collection by a `for..in` loop or something, which changes the order of elements. But it's interesting that this is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: I think they just didn't consider the possibility that a collection would have both connected and disconnected elements. The code isn't actually very careful about it.

Comment: @Barmar Do you think this is worth an issue to submit to the JQuery developers?

Comment: No, because the notion of document order doesn't make much sense when combining connected and disconnected elements. Also, there's a comment above the `isDisconnected()` function admitting that the test could be improved. Have you searched the bug list to see if anything like this is already reported?

Comment: There are a few issues ([#6205](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6205), [#5993](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5993), [#5791](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5791), [#1522](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1522)) with `add()` not behaving as expected or how it should behave when there are disconnected nodes back from 3 yrs ago but none of them mentions ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in jQuery looks like this:

```
    add: function( selector, context ) {
            var set = typeof selector === "string" ?
                            jQuery( selector, context ) :
                            jQuery.makeArray( selector && selector.nodeType ? [ selector ] : selector ),
                    all = jQuery.merge( this.get(), set );

            return this.pushStack( isDisconnected( set[0] ) || isDisconnected( all[0] ) ?
                    all :
                    jQuery.unique( all ) );
    },
```

So if the first element of the collection being added or the merged collection is disconnected, it just returns the merged collection, in whatever order `jQuery.merge()` happened to put them in. If they're both connected, it calls `jQuery.unique()`, which puts them in DOM order.

However, the comparison function for doing the sort is:

```
    function( a, b ) {
            if ( a === b ) {
                    hasDuplicate = true;
                    return 0;
            }

            return ( !a.compareDocumentPosition || !b.compareDocumentPosition ?
                    a.compareDocumentPosition :
                    a.compareDocumentPosition(b) & 4
            ) ? -1 : 1;
    }
```

This is then dependent on how the browser implements `compareDocumentPosition()` when comparing disconnected elements with connected elements, or disconnected elements with each other. I'd expect it to return `DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED` (1) in both cases, but Chrome returns 4 (`DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING`) in the latter case, and other combinations of bits in the first case.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. To keep the order right, using a native array as the collection and then converting it into a jQuery collection using the notation `$(nativeArrayReference)` seems like the only way to go, then. What do you think?

Comment: You haven't described what you're trying to accomplish, so it's hard to say. But if you want them to stay in the order that you add them, just use an array.

Comment: Later in the code I'm using jQuery functions on that collection so I ended up creating a native array, then converting it into a JQ collection when array modifications are over. Good to know what's actually happening with the `add()` function. Thanks again :)